# JavaScript visibility not working ('hidden' works, 'visible' doesn't)

Tags: javascript, visibility, business-process-management

I'm developing a solution using Lombardi Teamworks BPM Tool .. The tool itself generates the client-side source code, but I can put in code using JavaScript, such as adding onChange code for combo boxes ..

Anyways, I have a button whose visibility I'm trying to toggle using JavaScript. I am able to hide a button using `hidden`, but I cannot unhide a hidden button using `visible`.

Here's the full code:

```
var eleBtnVisibilityTest = document.getElementById("btnVisibilityTest");
if (eleBtnVisibilityTest== null) {
            eleBtnVisibilityTest = document.getElementsByName("btnVisibilityTest");
}

alert("-->"+eleBtnVisibilityTest.style.visibility+"<--");

eleBtnVisibilityTest.style.visibility = "visible";

alert("-->"+eleBtnVisibilityTest.style.visibility+"<--");
```

In the second last line, I'm setting the button to `visible`, but it's doesn't work ... However, if the button was previously visible, and I had written `hidden` here, it would've worked.

For both cases, in the alert *before* setting the visibility, the pop-up I get says `--><--` .. In the popup *after* setting visibility, its either `-->visible<--` or `-->hidden<--` ..

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CSS display property:

```
display: block;
display:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName` returns a NodeList, you must select an item from that list:

```
var eleBtnVisibilityTest = document.getElementById("btnVisibilityTest");
if (eleBtnVisibilityTest== null) {
            eleBtnVisibilityTest = document.getElementsByName("btnVisibilityTest")[0];
}
```

But however, when setting the visibility to hidden works, this actually is not the problem here.

You should provide more details, because your code works when used with getElementById
[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4mhBk/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4mhBk/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "but it's doesn't work" - do you mean that the button stays invisible?

It could be that the button is hidden by other means than the CSS `visibility` property. Maybe it also has `display: none`? In that case, setting the `visibility` property would not make the button become visible. Use a tool such as Chrome's inspector to check if that is the case.

Post a code snippet at JSFiddle, so we can see the code in action.